# Django+MongoDb connection error

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I am currently developing an application in Django+MongoDb. The application has to just push the data into the database once the url of the application is accessed.

But how ever I am encountering this error `mongoengine.connection.ConnectionError: Cannot connect to database default : port must be an instance of int`

As the error states port should be an 'int', I changed the port details from `mongoengine.connect('employeedb', host='127.0.0.1', port='8000')` to 
`mongoengine.connect('employeedb', host='127.0.0.1', port=8000)` in my settings.py file but then I get an error stating `mongoengine.connection.ConnectionError: Cannot connect to database default : [Errno 111] Connection refused`

Can anyone find out what is going wrong here?

I am using: `django==1.7, mongoengine, django-toolbox & pymongo==2.8`

My settings.py file is [here](https://github.com/iyerkiran/zaya/tree/master/zaya_project)

**EDIT: My OS= Ubuntu 14.04 & 
I have not installed django-nonrel**

Comment: did you change your mongodb from it's default port of 27017

Comment: No @ChrisHawkes Can you please guide me through the procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install mongodb in local pc and set dbpath,

Then open cmd and open connection using this command:

c:/mongodb/bin>mongod --dbpath (path of db)

and then replace you connection line in settings.py like this and run your project.

```
mongoengine.connect('employeedb', username='', password='')
```

Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing dummy database from DATABASES dict with the following, should work for you.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default' : {
      'ENGINE' : 'django_mongodb_engine',
      'NAME' : 'employeedb'    
    } 
}
```

Django MongoDB Engine also takes into account the HOST, PORT, USER, PASSWORD and OPTIONS settings.

For more help https://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/settings.html

Comment: After trying out your solution, I encounter and error `NotImplementedError: subclasses of BaseDatabaseIntrospection may require a get_table_list() method`. On researching further I came to know that my installed django doesn't support non-relational db and I need to download a **django-nonrel**  which is a fork of django and is supporting only django version 1.5 as of now and its 1.6 is in beta. So what do I do now?